# What happens when I "re-initialize" a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

I am currently writing a piece of code in c++ and I came across some behaviour that I don't understand. Let's say that I have a custom class(I'm not sure if it matters what goes on inside the class) and I want to make a pointer to this class:

```
AliAODEvent* aod;
```

Now, after I have made this pointer, I want to assign it to a memory location. In the framework that I am using, the object that I want to point to already exists somewhere, so what I did was

```
AliAODEvent* aod = (This is where the object I want to point to goes);
```

I realize now that I should just use `aod=(Object to point to);` But I am curious as to what happened when I tried to essentially "re-initialize" the pointer. Any thoughts?

Comment: You should get some kind of compilation error like `error: redefinition of 'aod'`

Comment: In addition to what has already been said: make sure to take note of the fact that references, unlike pointers, can't be reassigned. Other than that, there is nothing special about reassigning a pointer, since it's just an integer variable holding a memory address (assuming a simplified approach).

Comment: "*I want to assign it to a memory location*" - please make sure you understand the term "*assign to*". Here, you are assigning a value to the pointer, not vice versa. This is fundamental, pay attention to how you phrase things in programming.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you have *declaration* and *initialisation*.

```
int x;    // Declaration
x = 10;   // Initialisation
```

Declaring a variable means asking the operating system to allocate a place in memory for it. Initialising a variable means setting the value at that memory address for the first time. You can do both at once:

```
int x = 10;   // Declares x, then initialises it to 10
```

In C++ it is not allowed to declare a variable more than once:

```
int x;   // Declares x
int x;   // Tries to declare another variable also called x, fails (ERROR)
```

However, you CAN declare two variables with the same name as long as they are in different scopes:

```
#include <iostream>
int x = 10;

int main()
{

    int x = 20;

    {
        int x = 30;
        std::cout << x << ", " << ::x << std::endl;   // Prints '30, 10'
    }

    std::cout << x << ", " << ::x << std::endl;   // Prints '20, 10'

    return 0;
}
```

{} denotes new scope, and :: denotes global scope. So you can specify global scope, or you can use local scope, but you can't use anything else with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the statement

```
AliAODEvent* aod = (This is where the object I want to point to goes);
```

means "please create for me a new variable called `aod` of type `AliAODEvent*` and assign it a particular variable." On the other hand, the statement

```
aod = (This is where the object I want to point to goes);
```

means "find an existing variable called `aod` and assign it to point to a new location." The distinction here is that, by including the name of the type, C++ thinks you're giving a *declaration* that introduces a new variable, rather than an *assignment statement* that takes an existing variable and changes where it points. This is just how the language is designed.

The reason this second one works while the first doesn't is that you're ultimately trying to take something that exists and change it, which means you should *not* be providing a declaration. Generally speaking, you only should include the type of a variable in a statement if you're declaring that variable and otherwise should just use its name.

Answer (score 0):

You are not reinitializing the pointer in that case, but trying to create a pointer of the same name, which would be an error, unless it was in a different scope block.

ie:

```
AliAODEvent* aod;

{
   AliAODEvent* aod = (something)
}
```

In that case, the aod variable would be ok (although might show a warning) as would be a different vaiable, which would no longer be there once the scope of it (the '}') ended.

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
A* aod = &x;
A* aod = &y;
```

is declaring *two variables*, and is ill-formed. It should be rejected by most compilers but with the right settings some compilers may let it through.

What happened here is that the compiler created storage for the first variable and stored the address of `x` into it. Then it created *additional* storage for a second variable and *hid* the original variable.

At this point, the program is storing both the value of `x` and `y` in different memory locations, but you can only refer to the second `aod` until it goes out of scope.

This is usually called "shadowing" and is legal only between scopes:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {};

A a, b, c;

A* ptr = &a;

void report(A* p) {
    std::cout << (void*) &a << ", " << (void*) &b << ", " << (void*) &c
              << ": " << (void*) p << "\n";
}

int f() {
    std::cout << "f() ";
    report(ptr);
}

int main() {
    report(ptr);
    if (ptr != nullptr) {
        A* ptr = &b;
        report(ptr);
        if (ptr != nullptr) {
            A* ptr = &c;
            f();
            report(ptr);
        }
        report(ptr);
    }
    report(ptr);
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/LBFWFT

Also, be aware that pointers are *not* smart.

```
A* aod = new A;
aod = new A;
```

This allocates two `A`s but never frees the first one, because we never tell it to, we simply overwrite the value. The compiler does *not* keep a track of when a dynamic object is no-longer referenced.

```
int main() {
    A* aod = nullptr;
    if (aod == nullptr) {   // start new scope
        A x;
        aod = &x;
    }  // end scope, `x` is destroyed.
    use(aod);
}
```

This code introduces a bug: `aod` points to the address of `x`, but `x` is destroyed when it goes out of scope at the `}` so this pointer is `dangling` and references invalid memory.

Answer (score 0):

In giving the pointer an address to an existing location, you don't want to use the type specifier to the left of it again, since that variable already exists (that's declaring a variable). You won't be able to declare a new variable `aod` again while you are in the scope of the first `aod`.

Additionally, to be clear, saying `aod=(Object to point to);` is only correct if you have the *address of* the object after the assignment operator, **not** the object itself. You assign the address of an object to a pointer by using the `&` operator before the name of another object to obtain its address:

```
Object* objectPointer = &existingObject; //point objectPointer to the address of existingObject
```

Or, by a method,

```
Object* objectPointer = method()
```

where `method()` has a return type of `Object*` (pointer to an `Object` type).

You can also create a new object on the heap using the `new` operator:

```
Object* objectPointer = new Object("args");
```

which must be deleted with the `delete` operator when you're done with it.

```
delete objectPointer;
```

Remember that just because a pointer falls out of scope and stops existing, doesn't mean that the memory it points to does.